# Linq orderyby boolean

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by

I have a Linq query which returns an ordered list. It works, but when sorting boolean values it always puts the false items first.

```
return from workers in db.Workers
               orderby workers.active, workers.naam 
               select workers;
```

Is there a way to order the true items first?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the order by `descending` option and it will reverse the list.  See [MSDN Soring Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546145.aspx) for more examples on sorting.

```
return from workers in db.Workers
           orderby workers.active descending, workers.naam 
           select workers;
```

Answer (score 29):

The [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) method will sort items **in ascending order by default**. Now, given that the numeric representation of a boolean is:

- `false` = 0
- `true` = 1

`false` values will naturally come first. If you want to reverse the order just use the `descending` keyword:

```
return from workers in db.Workers
               orderby workers.active descending, workers.naam 
               select workers;
```